# How can I use two TensorFlow variables with identical names managed by different containers in the same graph?

Tags: scope, containers, tensorflow

I have no problem building and running a graph containing variables stored in different containers, but I can't find a way to use two different variables that happen to have the same name because TensorFlow automatically renames the second variable definition by adding a `_1` suffix.

For example, I first initialize a variable named `"x"` in container `"a"`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.container("a"):
    xa = tf.Variable(1.0, name="x")

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    sess.run(xa.initializer)
```

Then I initialize another variable named `"x"` in container `"b"`:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.container("b"):
    xb = tf.Variable(2.0, name="x")

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    sess.run(xb.initializer)
```

Now I would like use both of these variables in a new graph:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.container("a"):
    xa = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x")

with tf.container("b"):
    xb = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x") # renamed to x_1!

z = xa + xb

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    print(z.eval())
```

But TensorFlow automatically renames the second variable to `x_1`, so when I run this code I get an error telling me that `x_1` was not initialized.

Note: everything works fine if the variables don't have the same name so a quick workaround is to rename one of these variables, but it seems that there should be a way to do this since these variables are really different, except for their names.

**Edit**

For queues, the solution is easy since they have a `shared_name` attribute which is different from the `name` attribute, so you could write:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.container("a"):
    xa = tf.FIFOQueue(..., name="xa", shared_name="x")

with tf.container("b"):
    xb = tf.FIFOQueue(..., name="xb", shared_name="x")
```

But there does not seem to be a `shared_name` attribute for variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two variable with the same name in a graph.

I think the solution would be creating two graphs, and two remote sessions that points to a same remote endpoint.

```
import tensorflow as tf


g_1 = tf.Graph()
with g_1.as_default():
  c = tf.constant("Node in g_1")
  with tf.container("a"):
      x1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x")
  init1 = tf.global_variables_initializer()

g_2 = tf.Graph()
with g_2.as_default():
  d = tf.constant("Node in g_2")
  with tf.container("a"):
      x2 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="x")
  init2 = tf.global_variables_initializer()

server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
print server.target
sess_1 = tf.Session(server.target, graph=g_1)
sess_2 = tf.Session(server.target, graph=g_2)

assert c.graph is g_1
assert sess_1.graph is g_1

assert d.graph is g_2
assert sess_2.graph is g_2

print sess_1.run([init1, c])
print sess_1.run([x1])
print sess_2.run([x2])
```

You can see that `x2` is already initialized.

Note: must use remote session to make this work.

Reference:

[Graphs and Sessions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3c8ade09e75788a9f11865aa8275902d75fa4939/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/graphs.md#programming-with-multiple-graphs)

[Distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)